# Why is a calculation on integers truncated to an integer even though I've cast it to a float?

Tags: rust

The below code is returning an integer instead of a float even though the return type of the function is a `f32`.

```
fn main() {
    let temp = 37;
    let degree = 'F';
    let result = temp_conv(temp, degree);

    println!("The equivalent of {}{} is: {}", temp, degree, result);
}

fn temp_conv(value: u32, degree: char) -> f32 {
    let mut temperature: f32 = 0.0;

    if degree == 'C' {
        temperature = ((value - 32) * (5 / 9)) as f32;
    } else if degree == 'F' {
        temperature = ((value * 9 / 5) + 32) as f32;
    } else {
        temperature = 0.0;
    };

    temperature
}
```

I expect the output to be `98.6`, instead it is just `98`.

Comment: You may enjoy reading https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/207481 because you are doing the exact same mistake as the person on codereview does.

Comment: Note that your conversion is backwards from the message you print: you say `The equivalent of 37F is: 98` but 37°F is actually 2.8°C. You probably want to tweak the message.

Comment: Nopes, it is showing as i said..

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong about what the code does, I'm saying the `println!` is inconsistent. It says you convert Fahrenheit to Celsius but the code actually converts Celsius to Fahrenheit. It should presumably say `The equivalent of 37C is 98F` (assuming `degree` is meant to be the scale being converted *to*), which would be a true if somewhat imprecise statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing the math on the integer type (which causes the unwanted rounding) and cast it *afterwards* to `f32`.

```rust
fn main() {
    let temp = 37;
    let degree = 'F';

    let result = temp_conv(temp, degree);

    println!("The equivalent of {}{} is: {}", temp, degree, result);
}

fn temp_conv(value: u32, degree: char) -> f32 {
    if degree == 'C' {
        (value as f32 - 32.0) * (5.0 / 9.0)
    } else if degree == 'F' {
        (value as f32 * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32.0
    } else {
        0.0
    }
}
```

https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7e71b3b0dc6491d5a39716a2b85a32d8

Comment: Better with pattern matching https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=96da9e4aeebea6c058f4769790de597a

Comment: Please use rustfmt to format your code according to the guidelines of the community. You can find it in the upper right corner auf the playground under tools.

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios or even better with an enum

Comment: Is there a better way doing this? Writing each value as a float doesn't seem good. I am looking for some standard way of doing this..

Comment: @MuhammadOvais What's wrong with writing `5.0` when you mean `5.0`? Or do I misunderstand your objection?

Comment: You can write `5.`, but that's dubiously "better".

Comment: Thanks @chpio, i got the underlying science to some extent. To get the result of any expression, the participant members should be of same required data type. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @hellow, will follow the guidelines next time. Thanks.